# Match a string with regular expression

Tags: regex, expression

I have a problem to create a regular expression. I have a string like this (a simple json response froma  webserver):

```
{
    "key1":valueInt1,
    "key2":valueInt2,
    [...]
    "specialKey":"",
    "subtitle":"Every kind of character, like char, num or punct",
    "key3":"Useful line",
}
```

What I want is to delete the keys "specialKey" and its value and "subtitle" with its value. Both of them can be empty (like specialKey in my example).

I have tried something like that:

```
(\"subtitle\"\:\")([:punct:]*[:space:]*[:word:]*)*(\",)
```

Without success. The error is the part ([:punct:]*[:space:]*[:word:]*)* to match my random sentence.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In which language are you doing this? (see the regex tag description). Can you provide some examples of the values that can be present in specialKey?

Comment: Maybe you should use `JSONParser` function or class, that implement a parsing of a json. after that you can simple destroy your key/value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character classes are usually only used within bracket expressions. If you change what you have into:

```
(\"subtitle\"\:\")([[:punct:][:space:][:word:]]*)*(\",)
```

It should work.

Answer (score 3):

JSON [is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) so regular expressions are not the best tool for this kind of manipulation. You better use a JSON parser for achieving your goal.